# Java generic GetComponent method

Tags: java, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a java component system similar to that of the UnityEngine and wanted to build a generic GetComponent() method. I am stuck when trying to return the type found

```
    public <T> T GetComponent (){
    for (Component c: this.components){
    //I know this doesn't work, I want to know how to check if the type 
    //matches and return it (ie. Collider col = GetComponent<Collider>();)
        if(c == T)){
            System.out.println("Component of type: " + c.name + " found!");
            return T;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("No component found");
    return null;
}
```

## Edit

Thanks to all who answered. This has been a learning experience in just how much Java and C# differ.

Comment: In Java it is good practice to start method names with lower case characters - like `getComponent`. Read more here: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html

Comment: I know, I just prefer C# conventions

Comment: @EpicNicks, when in Rome...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I try to deduce from your text and code, what you are trying to achieve, then I do not see the need to use generics.

To me, it looks like you are trying to achieve this:

```
public Component getComponent (){
    for (Component c: this.components){
        //I know this doesn't work, I want to know how to check if the type 
        //matches and return it (ie. Collider col = GetComponent<Collider>();)
        if(c instanceof Collider) {
            System.out.println("Component of type: " + c.name + " found!");
            return c;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("No component found");
    return null;
}
```

I.e. to search a collection for an instance of type Collider. If this assumption is true, your method could be reduced to a oneliner:

```
public Collider getCollider (){
    return components.stream().filter(c -> c instanceof Collider).findFirst().orElse(null);
}
```

**EDIT**

With the comment from @EpicNicks below, this is an adaption of my proposal:

```
public <T extends Component> T getComponent (Class<T> componentClass){
    for (Component c: this.components){ 
        //I know this doesn't work, I want to know how to check if the type
        //matches and return it (ie. Collider col = GetComponent<Collider>();)
        if(c.getClass().isAssignableFrom(componentClass)) {
            System.out.println("Component of type: " + c.getClass().getSimpleName() + " found!");
            return (T) c;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("No component found");
    return null;
}
```

Comment: The reason I wanted to use generics is I will be using multiple component types. The gameObject will store up to one of each component and will be referenced by calling GetComponent<Type>()

Comment: Note, that I use Class#isAssignableFrom(componentClass) - this will also return true for subclasses. You need to consider if this is good for your application.

Comment: I must be forgetting basic java. How would you pass the class in the message?

Comment: @EpicNicks `SomeClass.class`, or `someObject.getClass()`

Comment: About to sign off for the Day, but how this method currently works, I would have to set ex: Collider col = (Collider)gameObject.GetComponent(Collider.class) since it extends component. How would the need to cast the result affect this implementation?

Comment: The is no need tor the cast - you should call the generic method like this: `Collider col = gameObject.getComponent(Collider.class);`.

Comment: The way I have things set up, Component is the base class of Collider. The compiler says collider must be assigned a collider while the method returns the parent type component

Answer (score 2):

You cannot `return T`. Returning takes an expression, not a type. `return T` is similar to `return String`, which is invalid.

You're trying to return a component, so probably:

```
public <T> T GetComponent (Class<T> compnentType)
    for (Component c: this.components){
        if(c.getClass() == compnentType)){ //you need to check your logic here
            System.out.println("Component of type: " + c.name + " found!");
            return (T) c;
        }
    }

    return null; //again, logic to be checked.
}
```

This checks component classes. You cannot check types without receiving the component class, because you cannot use the type parameter `T` in `instanceof` checks.

Comment: Is there a way to get this method to work only passing in generic parameters? Like in Unity's GetComponent<Type>()?

Comment: @EpicNicks You can use `T` to cast the return value, but you would have nothing to filter components with (so your `if` becomes impossible)

Comment: any idea how Unity might do it? is it just a matter of C# features?

Comment: @EpicNicks No idea, not familiar with that framework.

Comment: @EpicNicks, C# has .NET reflections, I don't know if Java has anything like that.

Comment: @jwdonahue Java has a powerful reflection library as well.

Comment: How is it handled in ArrayList<Type>()? would that be similar?

Comment: Java erases type arguments at runtime. That may be what's making the difference. You can't use `Type` from `ArrayList<Type>` during runtime.

Comment: C#'s generic system is different (no erasure, etc.), so while in most cases it looks the same as in Java, a call like `GetComponent<Type>()` is valid in C#, but not in Java.

Answer (score 0):

I can't check this right now, but perhaps this would accomplish finding the right type without passing in an argument:

```
public <T> T GetComponent () {
    for (Component c: this.components){
        try {
            return (T) c;
        } catch (ClassCastException cce) {}
    }
    return null;
}
```

}